# neo4j - how to set label with property value

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes without label but a property NodeType

Is there a way to set the label of those nodes with the value of the NodeType property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, currently there is no possibility to define a label with a variable.

You'll have to do it in your application by fetching all nodes that you want to add a label on it and sending a Cypher Query to add this label.

A quick example in PHP :

```
$nodes = $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) WHERE n.nodeType = "MyType" RETURN n');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $label = $node->getProperty('nodeType');
    $id = $node->getId();
    $client->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = '.$id.' SET n :'.$label;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a variable but you can still do it in a cypher query (or at least a few of them) rather than a script. If you only have a handful of different labels this probably works well but not that scalable for many labels.

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE length(labels(n)) = 0 
AND n.type = 'XX' 
SET n:XX;


MATCH (n) 
WHERE length(labels(n)) = 0 
AND n.type = 'XY' 
SET n:XY;
```

Comment: Nice answer. Happy to see such tweaks in Cypher.

Answer (score 3):

Using Cypher and APOC to move a property value to a label

```
// create a node with property studio
   create (n:Movies {name: 'A Few Good Men', studio: 'Warner Brothers'})
// move the 'studio' property to a label and remove it as a property
   MATCH (n:Movies)
   call apoc.create.addLabels([ id(n) ], [ n.studio ]) yield node
   with node
   remove node.studio
   return node
```

[`From`](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/using-cypher-and-apoc-to-move-a-property-value-to-a-label/)

Comment: The documentation for that APOC call is: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/property-value-label/

Answer (score 0):

A hack solution would be to have a Cypher query that looks something like:

```
start n=node({nodeId})
set n :LABEL with n
return labels(n)
```

And run some text manipulation on this query so that you would insert the label. Here is a java example:

```
String setNodeLabelQuery = getQueryString();
setNodeLabelQuery = setNodeLabelQuery.replaceFirst("LABEL", "LABEL_B);
```

Where `getQueryString()` is a method that returns the string of the query.