# Using variable to create relationship in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a relationship between nodes dynamically. The problem I am having is that I am unable to use a variable to specify the relationship type.

For example, I have the data:

```js
{
    nodes: [
        {
             "name":"Node1"
        },
        ...
    ],
    relationships: [
        {
             "sourceNode": "Node1",
             "destinationNode": "Node2",
             "relationshipType": "FRIEND"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Assume all nodes have been created.

I now want to create relationships between nodes of type `relationshipType`.

I'm trying to do this like so:

```
WITH {json} AS document
UNWIND document.relationships AS relationship
MATCH (pdt:Node {name: relationship.sourceNode})
MATCH (cdt:Node {name: relationship.destinationNode})
CREATE (pdt)-[r:relationship.relationshipType]->(cdt)
RETURN pdt.name,type(r),cdt.name
```

However it craps out at `[r:relationship.relationshipType]` because it is expecting an explicit type like `[r:CHILD]`.

Is it possible to use a variable to set a relationship type?

Comment: A related post is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536573/neo4j-how-to-set-label-with-property-value: "currently there is no possibility to define a label with a variable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running parametrized neo4j cypher query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205200/running-parametrized-neo4j-cypher-query)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After installing the [APOC plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), you can use the `apoc.create.relationship` procedure to create relationships with dynamic types.

For example:

```
WITH {json} AS document
UNWIND document.relationships AS relationship
MATCH (pdt:Node {name: relationship.sourceNode})
MATCH (cdt:Node {name: relationship.destinationNode})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(pdt, relationship.relationshipType, NULL, cdt) YIELD rel
RETURN pdt.name, type(rel), cdt.name
```